# Why pfgkeys don't redefine my command on default?

Tags: pgfkeys

I'm doing this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.is family,
  /foo,
  a/.estore in = \bar,
  a/.default = bye,
  a
}
\newcommand\go[1]{
  \pgfkeys{/foo, #1}
  \bar
}
\begin{document}
\go{a=hello}
\go{}
\end{document}
```

I expect the output to have `hello` and then `bye`, while it prints `hello` two times. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [@egreg said](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629577/117050) the assignments are local and `.default` sets a value which is used if no value is supplied.

A common (and often good) practice is to put a group around your usage in your own macro, this way the local assignments of one call can't influence another call, and that would result in the expected behaviour (the other option is what @egreg did, not using a group and restoring the defaults on each call).

So the following would work as well for your usage (like @egreg I changed the internal to `\fooa` to not affect `\bar`, and just like @egreg I removed the erroneous spaces from your definition by commenting out the line endings; and I changed `\pgfkeys{/foo,#1}` to `\pgfqkeys{/foo}{#1}` which is faster):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.is family,
  /foo,
  a/.estore in = \fooa,
  a/.default = bye,
  a
}
\newcommand\go[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/foo}{#1}%
    \fooa
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
\go{a=hello}
\go{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This approach also has a few advantages compared to "manually" resetting defaults: You could change the behaviour for multiple calls by using `\pgfkeys{/foo/a=something else}` outside of `\go` (you'd need to change the `.default` with the other approach which could have unwanted side effects on other usages). Also this scales better for more keys and is easier to maintain, imho. A disadvantage is that the group might limit other coding (but that's rarely an issue, really).

Answer (score 4):

You're misunderstanding what `.default` does: its purpose is to supply a value when the key is not followed by one. Thus, with your setting,

```
\pgfkeys{/foo,a=bye}
\pgfkeys{/foo,a}
```

are completely equivalent. On the other hand, your second call `\go{}` just performs

```
\pgfkeys{/foo}
```

and no value is supplied for `a`, so `\bar` retains its previous value, set at the same group level.

The resetting would be done if you define

```
\pgfkeys{
  /foo/.is family,
  /foo,
  a/.estore in = \fooa,
  a/.default = bye,
  a
}
\newcommand\go[1]{%
  \pgfkeys{/foo, a, #1}%
  \fooa
}
```

(I changed `\bar` to `\fooa`, in order not to clobber an existing command.)